# Directive doesn't always fire on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that grabs the height of a particular element and applies it to another.

But for some reason, it doesn't always fire on page load. I think maybe the there are cases in which the element is taking too long to load, and it might be a smarter idea to only process it once it has fully loaded. It seems to work well on page resize (sometimes).

Why is this and how can I fix it?

**For example:**

```
// grab information of div height here    

<div class="col-sm-6" id="left-photos" element-size key="leftPhotoSize"></div>

// apply it here

<div class="col-sm-6" ng-style="{ 'height': leftPhotoSize.height + 30 + 'px' }"></div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('adsomaApp')
  .directive('elementSize', function ($timeout, $window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var height, width;
        var measure = function () {
          height = element[0].offsetHeight;
          width = element[0].offsetWidth;
          if (attrs.key) {
            scope[attrs.key] = {
              height: height,
              width: width
            };
          }
          scope.elementSize = {
            height: height,
            width: width
          };
        };

        $timeout(function () {
          measure();
        });
        $window.load(function() {
          measure();
        });
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
          measure();
          scope.$digest();
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: Sure, u[dated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please put your measure function inside a $watch function and then followed by scope.$apply().

Comment: How can I do that - can I please see a code example?